# "Function already has a body" Windows forms class error

Tags: c++, forms, visual-studio, class

I'm trying to declare my variables in .h and give them a value in .cpp, but i'm getting this error: "function 'Name::Test::Test(void)' already has a body"

**Test.h**

NameSpace Name

{

public ref class Test : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:

Test (void) {

InitializeComponent();

}

//Variables

public:

short Test1;

int Test2;

}

}

---

**Test.cpp**

#include

Test::Test() {

Test1 = 0;

Test2 = 0;

}

Comment: the error message is rather clear. You already defined `Test::Test()` in the header, so you cannot define it again in the source

Comment: what should the constructor do? You have one definition `{ initializeComponents();}`  and the second one `{ Test1 = 0; Test2 = 0;}` but you can have only one